# How can I update many rows with SQL in a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table and one of the columns holds web addresses like: 'http://...' or 'https://...'.

The problem is that there are some invalid entries, like 'shttp://...' or '#http//...' (the first character is invalid) and I want to correct all of them.

I use the following SQL statement:

```
'SELECT [...] FROM MyTable WHERE WebAddress LIKE '_http%'
```

and I successfuly get the problematic rows.

But how am I going to change/correct all of them using an `UPDATE` statement?
If you have some other solution please share it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change the SELECT to an UPDATE (of course, with some syntax changes) with a "fix" expression

```
UPDATE
   MyTable
SET
    WebAddress = SUBSTRING(WebAddress, 2, 8000)
WHERE
    WebAddress LIKE '_http%'
```

Comment: shouldn't we use LEN(WebAddress)-1 instead of 8000?

Comment: @Veer: only if you want to use 2 functions rather than one... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Sub string property as you can trim odd letters .Also like '_word start' suitable for your question